# MacOS Parental controls - constant website requests and inconsistent permissions

Tags: permission, parental-controls

So I have set up parental controls for my little brother on a MacBook with MacOS High Sierra, with only a few websites permitted.

Problem 1:
I get CONSTANT requests to whitelist some random Subdomains. No matter how many I whitelist, it's like wack-a-mole they endlessly pop back up, is there any way for me to just have websites and their necessary Subdomains just work/whitelisted without constant popup BSery?

Problem 2:
I allow an app in the parental controls, I login to my brothers account, I need to allow the app again to be used indefinitely. I have allowed Chess to be executed like 5 times already and still cannot be sure that it will execute next time he tries to open it. I am beyond frustrated.

Would love some advice.